# Tikz path starting from inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles

How can I have an arrow, which goes from an outer node to an inner node, leave the outer node from the **inside** of its border. In the MWE below the arrow leaves the outer blue node's border from the outside and then loops back inside the node, which is circled in red. What I want is for the arrow to at no point leave the outer node, and go straight (or curved) from the border of the outer node to the border of the inner node.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
                    class/.style   = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, top color=blue!15, bottom color=blue!5, draw, align=center, inner sep=2mm},
                    inclass/.style = {class, inner sep=1mm, top color=red!15, bottom color=red!5},
                    larrow/.style  = {draw, -latex, arrows={-triangle 45}}]
  \node (LinkedQuadTree) at (5,-3) [class] {\textbf{LinkedQuadTree}\\\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node (QuadTreeNode) at (0,1) [inclass] {QuadTreeNode};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \path [larrow] (LinkedQuadTree) edge [loop, out=0, in=5] (QuadTreeNode);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from MWE]

Comment: Why you nested `tikzpicture`? If both nodes are in the same `tikzpicture` the solution of your problem is simple ...

Comment: @Zarko I nested `tikzpicture`s as I don't know any other way of nesting nodes in tikz

Comment: I see, I will make an example how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See, if the following MWE gives what you like to obtain:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=3mm,
  class/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, 
                  top color=blue!15, bottom color=blue!5, 
                  minimum height=22mm, inner sep=2mm,
                  align=center},
inclass/.style = {class, minimum height=6mm,
                  inner sep=1mm, top color=red!15, bottom color=red!5},
larrow/.style  = {draw, -latex, arrows=-triangle 45}
                        ]
\node[class]  (LQT) at (5,-3)           {\hphantom{\textbf{LinkedQuadTree}}};
\node[below=of LQT.north]               {\textbf{LinkedQuadTree}};
\node[inclass,above=of LQT.south] (LQN) {QuadTreeNode};
%
\draw[larrow] (LQT.east) to [out=240, in=5] (LQN.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code gives:

[image]

**Edit:** Slightly improved code with new arrow design and new guessing, where actually is arrow:

```
\documentclass[10pt, tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=2mm,
  class/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, 
                  top color=blue!15, bottom color=blue!5, 
                  minimum height=22mm, inner sep=1mm,
                  align=center},
inclass/.style = {class, minimum height=6mm,
                  inner sep=1mm, top color=red!15, bottom color=red!5},
larrow/.style  = {-{Triangle[flex]}}
                        ]
\node[class,minimum width=42mm]          (MN) {};
\node[below=of MN.north]           (LQT) {\textbf{LinkedQuadTree}};
\node[inclass,above=of MN.south]   (LQN) {QuadTreeNode};
%
\draw[larrow] (LQT.east) to [loop, right, out=-45, in=15] (LQN.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

In this MWE I replace `arrows` library with more powerful `arows.meta`, add library `bending` for manipulating with arrows by macro `flex`. And instead of `article`  now I use `standalone` document class (that you can see only image).

Small changes are in nodes names and used style. It is easy to see them from MWE code.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to make one small modification to make the inner node relative to LQT.north (but without telepathy you couldn't have known that!)

Comment: Meanwhile I prepare slightly improves version of my MWE. With new guessing, where the arrow should be :-=